# Aggregating timely data efficiently in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data like this:

```
set.seed(2020)
df_time = data.frame(Time = as.Date(1:100), value = round(runif(100, min = 0, 100)))
head(df_time)
```

```
          Time value
1   1970-01-02    65
2   1970-01-03    39
3   1970-01-04    62
4   1970-01-05    48
5   1970-01-06    14
6   1970-01-07     7
7   1970-01-08    13
8   1970-01-09    39
9   1970-01-10     0
10  1970-01-11    62
```

And this:

```
df = data.frame(from= as.Date(c(3,6, 20)),to= as.Date(c(8,7, 24)),)
head(df)
```

My goal is to mutate the dataframe `df` such that it adds the sum of the values between the two given dates (excluding the from date and including the to date), i.e.

```
        from         to sum_value
1 1970-01-04 1970-01-09       121
2 1970-01-07 1970-01-08        13
3 1970-01-21 1970-01-25       204
```

Atthe moment I am doing it with a loop but that takes way too long for the amount of data I have.
Does anyone knows a better solution (e.g. with dplyr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowwise()` in this case to tell `dplyr` to evaluate `df` row by row:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum_value = df_time %>% 
           filter(Time > from, Time <= to) %>% 
           pull(value) %>% 
           sum()) %>% 
  ungroup() # ungroup is used to restore default behaviour of dplyr

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   from       to         sum_value
#>   <date>     <date>         <dbl>
#> 1 1970-01-04 1970-01-09       121
#> 2 1970-01-07 1970-01-08        13
#> 3 1970-01-21 1970-01-25       204
```

This is how I would do since I find the code easy to understand. But it's basically still a loop under the hood as far as I get it.

A different and potentially faster approach could be to use `data.table`. I'm not as familiar with the syntax so there might be a better way, but this works:

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table
df_time <- setDT(df_time)
df <- setDT(df)

# duplicate Time column since foverlaps needs two of them
df_time <- df_time[, Time2 := Time]
# Since from day should not be included
df <- df[, from := from + 1]
  
setkey(df, from, to)
res <- foverlaps(df_time, df, by.x = c("Time", "Time2"), by.y = c("from", "to"), type = "within")
res <- res[, .(value = sum(value)), keyby = .(from, to)]
res[, from := from - 1]
#>          from         to value
#> 1:       <NA>       <NA>  4622
#> 2: 1970-01-04 1970-01-09   121
#> 3: 1970-01-07 1970-01-08    13
#> 4: 1970-01-21 1970-01-25   204
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the feeling it's much faster though, but definitely more elegant!

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried to see if there is a way in `data.table` to do this. Let me know if it is any faster.